# hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final : Configuration

Tags: java, hibernate

Error in hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final,

To classpath, added all the libraries from the folder hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required

Also added one more file in classpath viz.hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final
from the folder hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\jpa

```
Configuration config1 = new Configuration();
config1.addPackage("co.edu.dbobject");
config1.addResource("master_group.hbm.xml");
sessionFactory = config1.buildSessionFactory();

Session session1 = sessionFactory.openSession();
session1.beginTransaction();

List<MGroup> result = (List<MGroup>) session1.createQuery("FROM MGroup").list();

 for (MGroup obj1 : result ) {
        System.out.println(obj1.toString());
 }

session1.getTransaction().commit();

session1.close();

if (sessionFactory != null ) {
    sessionFactory.close();
}
```

> org.hibernate.boot.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping
>   document: master_group.hbm.xml (RESOURCE)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.InputStreamXmlSource.doBind(InputStreamXmlSource.java:46)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.UrlXmlSource.doBind(UrlXmlSource.java:36)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.bind(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:59)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.addResource(MetadataSources.java:274)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:499)
>           at com.edu.servlet.AddGroup.doPost(AddGroup.java:63)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637) 
>       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.calcXmlName(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.calcXmlName(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl.getTypes(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeElementPropertyInfoImpl.getTypes(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.size(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.hasNext(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.MappingBinder.hbmJaxbContext(MappingBinder.java:81)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.MappingBinder.doBind(MappingBinder.java:61)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.AbstractBinder.doBind(AbstractBinder.java:102)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:57)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.InputStreamXmlSource.doBind(InputStreamXmlSource.java:43)
>           ... 19 more

As suggested in following [InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34528305/invalidmappingexception-could-not-parse-mapping-document/38781895#38781895)
I do not know, where to change the JAXB library.

Sharing it here so as to be useful to someone.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Java? And what is in the xml file that cannot be parsed?

Comment: java version "1.6.0-beta2"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0-beta2-b86)
Mapping XML file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="co.edu.dbobject">
    <class name="MGroup" table="MASTER_GROUP">
        <id name="id" column="GROUP_ID">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="GROUP_NAME" type="java.lang.String"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

Comment: Java 1.6.0 beta???

Comment: Due to some restrictions, i have not been able to upgrade to latest java versions.

Comment: Yes well then you can also not upgrade to the latest version of Hibernate. But running a .0 beta version is worse, you can at least run the latest Java 6 patch version